# WebGL 2.0 compatibility?

Tags: webgl, webgl2

How can I understand if PC with certain GPU supports WebGL 2.0? Appreciate if you can provide any helpfull links to proved documentation.

Comment: I don't know if I can link to any docs but can say that WebGL2 needs at least OpenGL ES 3.0 (What WebGL2 is based on), OpenGL 3.3 (the version that supports the minimum needed features to emulate ES 3.0), or DirectX 11 (which is what [ANGLE](https://github.com/google/angle) uses) to emulate ES 3.0 on Windows. That said, browsers will blacklist GPUs with known buggy drivers so just because a user has a GPU that can run WebGL2 doesn't mean that user will be able to use WebGL2 as they might have old or buggy drivers that have been blacklisted by the browser.

Comment: @gman thanks for your reply. I know that WebGL 2.0 requires OpenGL  ES 3.0 and this is the only thing I found in the documentation. I have also heard that there are some blacklisted GPU's, for example, Intel HD 3000 which installed on some Macs is blacklisted and you can't use WebGL1.0 and WebGL2.0 on Chrome browser with this GPU. This is a good idea to take a look on DirectX 11,  I will investigate it.